# Problems installing Epson XP-432 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, printing

I can't install a new printer Epson XP-432. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The program Printers sees it but there's no driver on that program's list. I've managed to download and extract the relevant .ppd file from the epson page but then this comes up:

> Printer 'EPSON-XP-342-343-345-Series' requires the '/usr/lib/cups/filter//opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr/cups/lib/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper' program but it is not currently installed. Please install it before using this printer.

Can anyone help?

I have now managed to install the printer but it's not printing. In the properties of the printer there is a message that I'm missing a print filter.

Comment: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: Thanks Pilot - that's where I found and downloaded the driver for an amd64 - which i think is the one i want. only problem is that when I open that file and try to install epson-printer-utility in Ubuntu software it doesn't work. I press 'install' and it doesn't etc.

Comment: You need to download the driver, not the utility. Utility is good too, but it won't make the printer work. Copy the deb file to your home folder and then install the driver using `sudo dpkg -i filename` command. Then run `sudo apt install -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Download `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.14-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` from

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Copy it to your Home folder, then run

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.14-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

The second command will intall `lsb` and other dependencies if they are not already installed.

Then install the printer from System Settings. It will find the driver.

Comment: Pilot6 - That's got it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Just realising that now I can see the printer but it definitely can't print. Do you know what might be causing this - I see that this was the issue with the original post I posted a question mistakenly as an answer but the link they give on that answer doesn't work any more

Comment: Try to reboot. And did everything install without errors? And you can always edit your question to add some details.

Comment: Have rebooted no improvement. I can print test pages from the printer but not from the computer. Everything I'm printing from the computer is just running through - but there's no problem with anything on the printer itself. This appears to be the same issue as person who had the problem I first wrote my comment on. 

I think that there was some error when I unpacked it - how would I find that out now I've rebooted?

Comment: Install the package again and post error messages TO YOUR QUESTION if any.

Comment: Okay - I reinstalled - this time no errors and followed your instructions. Everyone is now working. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you can accept the answer to show that it works.

Comment: The `sudo dpkg...` command has to be repeated after the `sudo apt install -f`. No reboot or reinstall required.

Comment: I've accidentally deleted one of the files for this printer from the downloaded file where it was kept - tidying things up.

As the printer wasn't working I decided to uninstall it under Printers in System Settings - and then reinstall - except now it isn't coming back up. I've tried to reinstall all the drivers as previously but it is making no difference. It is asking for the device URI.

Nothing has changed with my computer except I mistakenly deleted this file - which I believe is now replaced but the problem is I can't see the printer to reinstall it.

Comment: Wondering if there is any way to escalate this so I might get a suggestion as I'm not having much success. I thought about reinstalling Ubuntu as I hear that sometimes works as I guess something has set incorrectly. 
I have tried to purge and reinstall cups but not much effect with that.

Comment: You can always ask a new question.