# Difficulty installing Epson XP-432 printer

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, epson

I [previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952031/problems-installing-epson-xp-432-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) installed an epson printer and downloaded appropriate drivers - unfortunately I believe that clearing up my documents file I deleted one of the drivers without realising it.

The problem is now that as the printer wasn't working I proceeded to uninstall it under Printers in System Settings - and then reinstall - except now it isn't being recognised when I try to reinstall printer. I've tried to reinstall all the drivers as previously but it is making no difference. It is asking for the device URI. Nothing has changed with my computer except I mistakenly deleted this file - which I believe is now replaced but the problem is I can't see the printer to reinstall it.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the driver?

Comment: Yes I've tried to reinstall the driver.

Comment: so Donal, Epson now seem to recommend a generic driver;  was updated 27th Dec, http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=68680&DSCCHK=b0b2a070cb35bd28cbff91002aef457c9fc55487 so for 64bit Ubuntu it comes down as epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.18-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb. There is another printer driver called Turboprint and it provides very high quality drivers for many devices http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Epson_XP430series and one can download a cost-free evaluation copy; you could see if it is better; full copy is a few beers eqiv

Comment: The problem with outside links the one mentioned in this comment is gone. http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=68680&DSCCHK=b0b2a070cb35bd28cbff91002aef457c9fc55487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all of your installed packages which match 'cups', run

> dpkg -l | grep cups

Then just remove them with

> apt-get purge "packages"

Even after that, there could be some cups processes running. A simple reboot will eliminate them (an alternative would be to manually kill them).

> apt install lsb