# How to install Epson l120 printer driver with dependency problem?

Tags: apt, dependencies

```
zhulfa95 $ sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-201310w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package epson-inkjet-printer-201310w:i386.
(Reading database ... 206385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack epson-inkjet-printer-201310w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-201310w:i386 (1.0.0-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-201310w:i386:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201310w:i386 depends on lsb (>= 3.2).
dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-201310w:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201310w:i386
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: possible answers  https://askubuntu.com/a/992015/397428